# Method for external token-based Wordpress authentication

Tags: node.js, wordpress, cookies, authentication

Is there a methodology for using the Wordpress REST API with third party client authentication?

I'm looking for a way to allow my clients to "Login with Wordpress" on my site, then pass back a token to it, so I can post for them in the future.

The API offers very straightforward header authentication with User and Password, as well as Cookie based authentication, but is there support for cookie token storage and third party use, or is this explicitly forbidden?

Note, this would ideally not involve any alterations to the client's Wordpress account - only a "Login with Wordpress" methodology, ala Facebook or Twitter.